# How to prevent & conversion to &amp; when using JavaScript? (browser specifc)

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, html-escape

I have a problem concerning string output on HTML page when using Javascript and ASP. Logic of page generation goes like this:

1. We use asp page to generate HTML code using `Response.Write()`. If string contains numeric character reference (for example `&#1057;`) it would show on the user's side just fine as a character.
2. After that we add `OnLoad` event, which calls for a Javascript function. All this happens inside `<body><\body>` tags. Source for JavaScript added inside `<script></script>` tags. The function only adds `document.href`, which contains reference to the same asp page.
3. The asp logic loads again and adds some text to the page using `Response.BinaryWrite()` (Response.Write can be used all the same) All character references are shown as codes:`&#1057;`. Obviously all '&' symbols become `&amp;`(asp automatic conversion), browser decodes it as & and we can only see a code `&#1057;` and not the symbol 'С'.

As far as I know such behaviour can be caused by `<script>` tags, as a precaution against xss attacks. In the end I want to stop encoding '&' as `&amp;`.

However here is the most important part:

If I add header with "Content-Type" "text\html", IE (any version) starts encoding NCR symbols in a correct way. But Firefox, Chrome and Safari do not change behavior and keep encoding & as `&amp;`. I can see several questions on Stack Overflow which looks like mine, yet the situation is not exactly the same (My strings are not inserted directly by JavaScript, so I cannot manipulate output string and change `&amp;` to &, also my strings have correct symbols in the first place, they get changed by asp or by browser). Is there any elegant way to force Firefox or Chrome to decode page as IE? Maybe some settings or attributes in HTML tags? This problem looks like it depends on a browser to me, am I right?

Comment: It's not caused by the `<script>` tags. It's happening on the ASP side.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well, I really think it is a combination of ASP restrictions and `<script>`, because ASP does not mess with string output when I add it in the first step.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing about a plain `<script>` tag, or JavaScript code, that re-applies HTML escapement to text, unless it's *explicit* JavaScript code that's doing it. The mere presence of a `<script>` tag, in other words, has nothing to do with your problem. It also has nothing to do with the MIME header.

Comment: I see. So the only way to correct this problem is to call other ASP function from Response object?

Comment: It's not really clear exactly what the problem is; you have not posted any of the code involved.

Comment: If it is happening on the ASP side could you do replace your response.write(YourVariable) with response.write(Replace(YourVariable, "&amp;", "&"))

Comment: My variable does not contain &amp; so I think this won't work.

Comment: If the &amp;s are coming out of your Response.Write statement then it should work.  Response.Write doesn't automatically convert & to &amp; - you need to use Server.HTMLEncode to do that.  If you could post your code it would be much easier to work out what is happening

Comment: The problem is that code is pretty complicated: asp methods are called through COM interface and there are a lot of things generated on the page, so without context it is hard to tell what is what. I tried to descripe the problem without posting any actual code because of this. Anyway if we do not post my content but, for example `Response.Write(&#1057;)` it would still be `&#1057;` on the output. So I cannot see how Replace can help here.

Comment: Also what code is needed? Code of the page which is generated or ASP methods I use to compose the page?

Comment: The ASP/VBScript code which contains the response.write statement which is producing the errors.  I've just been experimenting and I think Response.BinaryWrite may be the cause of your problem.  Through the Opera btowser <% Response.BinaryWrite("&#1057;") %> becomes &#1057; while <% Response.Write("&#1057;") %> gives C.  Similarly Response.BinaryWrite gives &amp; where Response.Write gives &.  Also, if I use BinaryWrite and do a View Source I see nothing

Comment: I was playing with these functions too, response.write won't help in this situation, problem is not in BinaryWrite. I had a link to a nice asp documentation where it was said, when using <script></script> ASP automatically converts & to &amp;. I really wish to avoid that.